# PHP echo a variable only once if array returns at least one value

Tags: php

Ok so I have value being returned from a database in an `ARRAY` Some pages have 3 values, and some pages have 10, and other have 0.

If a page returns a value I want the label to appear ONCE, hence not in the loop.
label -> `$key_label = '<span class="hl_reference"><u>key references:</u></span>';`

If the page doesn't have any `$reference_keys` I don't want the label to appear, hence `$key_label = false;`

So I want to check the `ARRAY` for a value and if >= 1: the label will also appear.

My code doesn't seem to be validating `if(array($value => 1) && !$key_label)` I guess my syntax is wrong or maybe I should be using a different function?

Thanks for help!

```
$key_label = false;
$key_label = '<span class="hl_reference"><u>key references:</u></span>';

foreach($reference_keys as $value)
{
    echo $value .'&nbsp;';
}

if(array($value => 1) && !$key_label) 
{
    $key_label = true; 
    echo $key_label;
};
```

-------------------------------UPDATE-----------------------------

This code appears to only work on pages with only 1 reference_key... Strange as `count is set to >= 1`

```
$key_label = '<span class="hl_reference"><u>key references:</u></span>';

foreach($reference_keys as $value)
{
   echo $value .'&nbsp;';
}
$result = count($value);
if ($result > 1)
{
  echo $key_label;
}
```

-------------------------------UPDATE-----------------------------

Most recent code by John C appears to work but it displays a "1" immediately before the 2nd `$reference_key` on each page. But it does only display on pages with `$reference_key`

```
$key_flag = false;
$key_label = '<span class="hl_reference"><u>key references:</u></span>';

foreach($reference_keys as $value)
{
if (!empty($value)) {
    if (!$key_flag) {
        echo $key_label;
        $key_label = true;
    }
    echo $value .'&nbsp;';
}
};
```

-------------------------------UPDATE-----------------------------

John C solved this one.. Working code below! Thank you everyone! ->

```
$key_flag = false;
$key_label = '<span class="hl_reference"><u>key references:</u></span>';

foreach($reference_keys as $value)
{
if (!empty($value)) {
    if (!$key_flag) {
        echo $key_label;
        **$key_flag = true;**
    }
    echo $value .'&nbsp;';
}
};
```

Comment: Hey Rocket, i tired `if (count($value >= 1)` It's not working ... PHP manual is quite confusing to me...

Comment: You seem to be using $key_label for two different things. Can you show us what the array looks like? I assume $reference_keys is the array in question?

Comment: 1. Your syntax is (almost) disgusting. $key_label doesn't have the right values.

2. Can you show us your array?

Comment: my `ARRAY` is returned from the database `$reference_keys = array();`

Comment: @JohnC yes your assumption is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read this right, you would like to display the `span` if there are values in your `$reference_keys` array, then loop through and show the values in the array.

To do this, you could do something like:

```php
if (!empty($reference_keys) && count($reference_keys) > 0) {
    echo '<span class="hl_reference"><u>key references:</u></span>';
    foreach($reference_keys as $value)
    {
       echo $value .'&nbsp;';
    }
}
```

**EDIT** If there are empty values in the `$reference_keys` array, then the `count` will come back greater than 0 but no keys will show. If this is the case this code will work around:

```
$key_flag = false;
$key_label = '<span class="hl_reference"><u>key references:</u></span>';

foreach($reference_keys as $value)
{
    if (!empty($value)) {
        if (!$key_flag) {
            echo $key_label;
            $key_flag = true;
        }
        echo $value .'&nbsp;';
    }
}
```

Comment: This code ALWAYS shows the label -> even on pages without a key.. :(

Comment: @FabioAnselmo - changed to match your new code, with fix so you check `count()` for the `$reference_keys` variable.

Comment: Doesn't show for pages with 1 ref_key link.. Additional the `span` needs to display before the `$value`

Comment: @FabioAnselmo - alright, possibly we have empty values in the array, new code to work around that posted.

Comment: Hey @John C your last code almost works 98% there..  Just 1 hiccup. It's throwing in a '1' before the second link displayed...

Comment: @FabioAnselmo - oops I set the wrong variable to `true`! Fixed the line within the loop to `$key_flag = true;`

Comment: Yes sir you got it!! Great -- thank you very much.. I thought this was going to be a simple code with a simple solution.. that was 2 hours ago.. Sheesh.. Thanks again John!

Comment: Heh, I'm very glad we got there in the end! In future if you are posting questions it might help to post the a `var_dump` of any problem variables ($reference_data in this case), since that would have greatly sped up finding a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The [count](http://php.net/count) function should help you:

```
if(count($value) >= 1 && !$key_label)
```

Comment: `$value = array(0 => 'data1', 1 => 'data2');`
It couldn't be more clear ;)
Good night

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to have some logical problems, firstly you are overwriting the `$key_label` content and below in your code you are using [count()](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.count.php) in a variable that seems isn't an array. Try something like this code:

```
$key_flag  = false;
$key_label = '<span class="hl_reference"><u>key references:</u></span>';

foreach( $reference_keys as $value )
{
    echo $value .'&nbsp;';
}

if( count( $reference_keys ) >= 1 && ! $key_label )
{
    $key_flag = true; 
    echo $key_label;
};
```

Or you can use better solutions like this:

```
if( is_array($reference_keys) && count($reference_keys) > 0 )
{
    echo '<span class="hl_reference"><u>key references:</u></span>';

    foreach( $reference_keys as $value )
        echo $value .'&nbsp;';
}
```

**EDIT 1**

```
if( is_array($reference_keys) && count($reference_keys) > 0 )
{
    echo '<span class="hl_reference"><u>key references:</u></span>';

    foreach($reference_keys as $value)
        echo $value .'&nbsp;';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't do it.. Same result as my previous code. Check my update posting in a sec...

Comment: Marcio, the second code ALWAYS shows the label -> even on pages without a key.. No bueno..

Comment: and when I change `> 1` to `>= 1` It shows on all pages - including those with NO ref keys to show...

Comment: @FabioAnselmo, I think there is some problem with your variables. What kind of array `$reference_keys` receives?

Comment: `TEXT` type from `MYSQL` database table

Comment: @FabioAnselmo, What function are you using to fetch the resulto? [mysql_fetch_array()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)?